# How can I extract key values form my JSON dictionary?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to extract or (slice?) every value with the same key from my JSON dictionary array of arrays.

For this case, I want to slice the values for `beta` key and put them in a series.

`console.log(buckets[0].bucket_beta)`

```
0: {symbol: "A", beta: 0.9266892815140224}
1: {symbol: "AAP", beta: 0.8514784555010262}
2: {symbol: "ADT", beta: 1.4008075473180654}
```

Reason being, I would like to calculate the SUM of all values for beta and find the average.

```
export function calculateAvgValue(series)
{
    return series.reduce(function(sum, a) { return sum + a },0)/(series.length||1);
}
```

The issue with this dictionary object above, is that the beta values are each in their own seperate array.

Here is how I try to call my function and pass the object. However the problem is I don't know how to refer to every value of `beta` for the specific object.

```
calculateAvgValue(bucket.bucket_beta)
```

How can I properly get all the values specific to `beta` for each array in the object?

Comment: `return sum + a.beta`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  sum + b.beta. example as follows.

```js
const dictionary = [{symbol: "A", beta: 0.9266892815140224},
{symbol: "AAP", beta: 0.8514784555010262},
{symbol: "ADT", beta: 1.4008075473180654}]

const average = dictionary.reduce((a,b) => a + b.beta, 0)
console.log('average', average / dictionary.length)
```